# Having a user download a file through JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, browser

I am trying to have a button that users can click to download a file, but the file may not exist because it is a zipped file of other files and has to be generated. I am checking this with AJAX but once I recieve a proper URL I'm not sure how to have the user download it.

`window.open(link, '_blank');` tries to open the window to download the file, but most browsers prevent this and treat it as a pop-up. What is the best practice for having a user download a file like this? Thanks.

Here is the JS function I am using for reference:

```
function getDownloadedFiles() {
    var INTERVAL_TIME = 3000,
        $projectView  = $('#project-view'),
        id            = $projectView.data("project-id");
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: AJAX_URL + id,
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.success) {
                var link =  data.profiler.link;
                window.open(link, '_blank');
            } else {
                setTimeout(getDownloadedFiles, INTERVAL_TIME);
            } 
        }
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Get rid of the Window.open.  If the file can't be handled by the browser automtically, it will open the SaveAs dialog by itself.  Unless the user has a preference set already, in which case, it will just download the file to their drive, and notify them when it's done.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Download File Using Javascript/jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749231/download-file-using-javascript-jquery)

Comment: I looked into that question and the solution wasn't working for me.

Comment: I discovered I wasn't calling the correct URL, so the code did work. I'm gonna delete this question though because it is a duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

In the end, the correct solution was [Download File Using Javascript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749231/download-file-using-javascript-jquery) and I was using the wrong URL.

I was setting the link to be data.profiler.link when really it was data.data.link and confused myself.

Here is my final code:

```
function getDownloadedFiles() {
    var INTERVAL_TIME = 3000,
        $projectView  = $('#project-view'),
        id            = $projectView.data("project-id");
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: AJAX_URL + id,
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.success) {
                var link =  data.data.link,
                    hiddenIFrameID = 'hiddenDownloader',
                    iframe = document.getElementById(hiddenIFrameID);
                if (iframe === null) {
                    iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
                    iframe.id = hiddenIFrameID;
                    iframe.style.display = 'none';
                    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
                }
                iframe.src = link;
            } else {
                setTimeout(getDownloadedFiles, INTERVAL_TIME);
            } 
        }
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you can use a hidden iframe for that matter. Try this:

```
var downloadURL = function downloadURL(url) {
    var hiddenIFrameID = 'hiddenDownloader',
    iframe = document.getElementById(hiddenIFrameID);
    if (iframe === null) {
        iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        iframe.id = hiddenIFrameID;
        iframe.style.display = 'none';
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    }
    iframe.src = url;
};
```

Just a shameless rip of [Download File Using Javascript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749231/download-file-using-javascript-jquery)

Comment: Maybe you could show some more code of how you used the mentioned thread to work with yours.

Comment: I discovered I wasn't calling the correct URL, so the code did work. I'm gonna delete this question though because it is a duplicate.